# Detecting smoke and bluring/filtering using CNN in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, cnn

I need some help to make an CNN via python to detection of fire-smoke and make the fire-smoke blur. What should I do where can I start some help please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a book on [Methods and Techniques for Fire Detection](https://books.google.de/books?id=5MsHBgAAQBAJ).

[Computer vision based method for real-time fire and flame detection](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167865505001819) is one of the most cited papers on this topic. However, CNN is not a widely applicable method here.

**Update**:

Here is [implementation](https://github.com/tobybreckon/fire-detection-cnn) of [EXPERIMENTALLY DEFINED CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORK ARCHITECTURE
VARIANTS FOR NON-TEMPORAL REAL-TIME FIRE DETECTION](https://breckon.org/toby/publications/papers/dunnings18fire.pdf).